# How can I add an element to a template before a list of elements?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a frame with a StackLayout inside of it.  What I would like to do is before the items are added to the inside of the frame then I would like Heading label to appear.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ContentFrame : Frame
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };
    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Heading), typeof(string),
            typeof(ContentFrame), null, propertyChanged: OnHeadingChanged);

    public string Heading
    {
        get => (Heading)GetValue(HeadingProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeadingProperty, value);
    }

    public ContentFrame()
    {
        Content = contentStack;
        HasShadow = false;
        SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "ContentFrameBackgroundColor");
        SetDynamicResource(BorderColorProperty, "ContentFrameBorderColor");
        SetDynamicResource(CornerRadiusProperty, "ContentFrameCornerRadius");
    }
}
```

What I would like is to be able to use it like this:

```
 <t:ContentFrame Heading="The heading here">
    <Label Text="ABC" />
    <Label Text="ABC" />
    <Label Text="GHI" />
 </t:ContentFrame>
```

and have the output look like this:

```
 ********************
 * The heading here *
 * ABC              *
 * DEF              *
 * GHI              *
 ********************
```

Does anyone know how I can modify ContentFrame so that the heading is added as an element before the containing elements?

Here's the current code I am trying based on Shubham's suggestion:

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Contents")]
public class ContentFrame : CustomFrame
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };
    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }

    public ContentFrame()
    {
        var heading = new Label();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Heading))
        {

            heading.Text = Heading;
            contentStack.Children.Insert(0, heading);
        }
        Content = contentStack;
        HasShadow = false;
        SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "ContentFrameBackgroundColor");
        SetDynamicResource(BorderColorProperty, "ContentFrameBorderColor");
        SetDynamicResource(CornerRadiusProperty, "ContentFrameCornerRadius");
        SetDynamicResource(ElevationProperty, "ContentFrameElevation");
        SetDynamicResource(MarginProperty, "ContentFrameMargin");
        SetDynamicResource(PaddingProperty, "ContentFrameBorderPadding");
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Heading), typeof(string), typeof(ContentFrame), null);


    public string Heading
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeadingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeadingProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and code, you want to create custom frame with bindableproperty, I modify your code, please take a following code. Don't forget implement bindableproperty propertyChanged method.

```
public class ContentFrame : Frame
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };

    Label headinglabel { get; set; } = new Label()
    {
        TextColor=Color.Red
    };
    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Heading), typeof(string),
            typeof(ContentFrame), null, propertyChanged: OnHeadingChanged);

    private static void OnHeadingChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var customframe = (ContentFrame)bindable;
        customframe.headinglabel.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }

    public string Heading
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(HeadingProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeadingProperty, value);
    }

    public ContentFrame()
    {
        contentStack.Children.Add(headinglabel);
      
        Content = contentStack;
        HasShadow = false;
       
    }
}

<ContentPage
x:Class="demo3.customcontrol.Page4"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:demo3.customcontrol">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <control:ContentFrame Heading="The heading here">
            <control:ContentFrame.Contents>
                <Label Text="ABC" />
                <Label Text="ABC" />
                <Label Text="GHI" />
            </control:ContentFrame.Contents>

        </control:ContentFrame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will check this solution out now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
public class ContentFrame : Frame
{
    Label headingLabel { get; } = new Label()
    {
        FontSize = 18,
        Text = "default",//or string.Empty or null
        //Style = Use some header style
        TextColor = Color.Green
    };
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
    };
    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeadingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Heading), typeof(string),
            typeof(ContentFrame), null, propertyChanged: OnHeadingChanged);

    public string Heading
    {
        get => (Heading)GetValue(HeadingProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeadingProperty, value);
    }

    public ContentFrame()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Heading))
        {
            headingLabel.Text = Heading;
            contentStack.Children.Insert(0, headingLabel);
        }
        Content = contentStack;
        HasShadow = false;
        SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "ContentFrameBackgroundColor");
        SetDynamicResource(BorderColorProperty, "ContentFrameBorderColor");
        SetDynamicResource(CornerRadiusProperty, "ContentFrameCornerRadius");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are having headingLabel { get; } = new Label().  Can you take the code of my questions, copy / paste and add in your answer suggestion so it's really clear.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out later and update you.

Comment: Can you tell me what's the "OnHeadingChanged" for ?

Comment: It's in your code, @Alan2, it can be used to change the label's value if heading property is changed

Comment: I tried to implement your code (see updated code in the question), but it does not include the words "The heading here" as a label inside the frame when I enter <t:ContentFrame Heading="The heading here">